# 'if' statement doesn't work in 'for' loop

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I need to find whether an array of integers contains one or more elements that divides the array into two parts such that the sum of the elements in the left and the right parts are equal.

I tried this:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,3,2,1]

left_sum = 0
right_sum = arr.inject(0) { |sum, x| sum = sum + x } 

for i in 0..arr.length-1
  counter = []
  right_sum = right_sum - arr[i]

  case i
    when 0
    left_sum = 0          
  else
    left_sum = left_sum + arr[i-1]
  end

  puts "Left sum of element #" + i.to_s + "=" + left_sum.to_s
  puts "Right sum of element #" + i.to_s + "=" + right_sum.to_s
  puts " "

  if right_sum - arr[i] == left_sum + arr[i-1]
    puts "Left sum" + "=" + "Right sum"
    counter.push(i)
  end

  puts counter.to_s

end
```

I encountered an error. I do not understand why the `if`-statement doesn't work in the `for`-loop. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: There is not error message. Program just counts left and right sums and shows them, but the strings  <br/>   if right_sum - arr[i] == left_sum + arr[i-1]
    puts "Left sum" + "=" + "Right sum"
    counter.push(i)
  end  <br/> do not work.

Answer (score 1):

*Sidenote:* `for` loops are counter-idiomatic in ruby (read: nobody uses `for` loops in ruby.)

The problem with your code is in the last comparison. You already have sums calculated, hence you shouldn’t alter them:

```
# if right_sum - arr[i] == left_sum + arr[i-1]
if right_sum == left_sum
  puts "Left sum" + "=" + "Right sum"
  counter.push(i)
end
```

Also, I strongly suggest to rewrite this solution using [`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D) and [`Array#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sum).

Answer (score 1):

In ruby is not a good idea to use `for`, you can use `each` for loops in Ruby.

```
arr.each { |i|
   ...
}
```

Also you need to have already calculated the sum before ask if are equals.

```
right_aux = right_sum - arr[i]
left_aux = left_sum + arr[i-1]
if right_aux == left_aux
  puts "Left sum" + "=" + "Right sum"
  counter.push(i)
end
```